# What will happen if Aizawa uses his quirk on Invisible Girl?

Tags: my-hero-academia

There's [an image meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEr9G.png) posted on [r/Animemes](https://www.reddit.com/r/Animemes/comments/9uqob3/wait_a_moment/):

> If Aizawa's quirk nullifies others' quirk, what will happen if he uses it on Invisible Girl?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Shota_Aizawa),

> his quirk doesn't work on Mutation-Class quirks, which are distinguished by permanent alterations to the body. Invisibility is one of [those](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Mutant_Quirks) that are classified as Mutation-Class.

Answer (score 1):

I think Hagakure's quirk can be put under the category of "mutation" which to my belief Aizawa can't erase due to the quirk being part of their structure. It's also true that he has to actually see the person to be able to erase their quirk so that other factor is certainly true. When she was 1-3 she would have been born with a mostly normal appearance; however with all mutant types the quirk would have been at least partially noticeable.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your answer.