# Would Mineta stop producing the purple balls if Eraser Head used his quirk?

Tags: my-hero-academia

If Eraser Head tried to erase Mineta's quirk, would he stop producing the purple balls or would it not affect him because it is technically a form of physical quirk?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what is stated [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49547/what-will-happen-if-aizawa-uses-his-quirk-on-invisible-girl/49548#49548), *Shota Aizawa's quirk do not work on Mutation-class quirk and Mineta's quirk is [classified as one](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Pop_Off)*.

So no, **Mineta cannot stop producing purple balls even if Eraser Head used his quirk**.